# Assign Jinja2 block variable from for loop in view

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

How would I replace the the hard coded '`python`' with `snippet['language']` from a for loop in my view?

```
{% highlight 'python', lineno='inline' -%}
    {{snippet['code']}}
{% endhighlight %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply put your variable in place of the hardcoded string like this:

```
{% set lang = 'python' %}
{% highlight lang %}
  from fridge import Beer
  glass = Beer(lt=500)
  glass.drink()
{% endhighlight %}
```

You haven't showed us your for-loop, but in principle you can do the same thing in the for-loop too:

```
{% for lang in ['python', 'ruby', 'scheme'] %}
  {% highlight lang %}
  from fridge import Beer
  {% endhighlight %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this throws an error if you {% set lang = snippet['language'] %}

Comment: @IslandNic see my updated answer without setting a variable, maybe this example will help. What kind of error it throws?